# Netflix Eureka Redirection Issue In A Spring Based Project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I am trying to use Netflix eureka for service discovery and redirection from one microservice to another (Client-1 to Client-2) in a spring boot project using service name but somehow the redirection isn't working.

Below are the config and code i am using. Let me know what i am doing wrong.

**Server config :**

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.server.wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty=0


management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

**Client-1 config**

```
#Service discovery
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=1
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds=2

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true

spring.application.name=parent
```

**Client-2 Config**

```
#Service discovery
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=1
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds=2

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true

spring.application.name=admin
management.security.enabled=false
```

Now on the parent code i have mentioned the redirection value in **application.properties** as

```
admin.front.micro.services=http://admin (Have tried without http also)
```

And for redirection i am using it like

```
@Value("${admin.front.micro.services}")
private String adminFrontMicroServices;

String user=CookieUtils.getUser(request);
modelMap.addAttribute("usr", user);
String project=CookieUtils.getProject(request);
modelMap.addAttribute("proj", project);
return new ModelAndView("redirect://" + this.adminFrontMicroServices, modelMap)
```

I have tried using ipadress property but still it doesn't work.

One thing to note is i am using windows 10 and the service get's registered as

host.docker.internal

but after setting the inet iprange and preferipadress property it started showing as ipaddress but still the redirection is not working.

Need some advice on where i am wrong.

Comment: Why do you want to redirect in the first place? Wouldn't be better to use the advantage of feign client?

Comment: will feign be able to do ui redirection and handle cookies and modelmap?

Not really worked with feign.